# Windows Iot and Azure IoT Hub tutorial

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

Is there any good tutorial which guides to use Azure IoT Hub via using the Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT Core?

Comment: Get NOOBS and install IoT on the RPi, then Google a tutorial on how to build windows apps for windows IoT

Comment: Hi Michael and welcome to S.O.  Recommendations for tutorials are off-topic.  A simple Google search will lead you to tons of good tutorials.  Here's one on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPRUbGIyODY

Comment: Hi you can get started from Windows IoT if you are starter episode by episode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-kazyOiBvs it goes upto Azure IoT Hub. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/getting-started-with-windows-10-iot-core-raspberry-pi-3b/

Answer (score 1):

**First follow the steps from Zimano in the comments:**

Get NOOBS install Windows IoT Core with Noobs.

To do this, look at this page: [How to install OS with NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/2/) (Choose Windows IoT Core instead of Raspian, at the first start from NOOBS)

**Go to [Azure IoT Hub documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted) and follow this steps:**

1. Create an IoT hub (Do this in the Azure Portal)
2. Create a device identity (Do this in a console application)
3. Create a simulated device app <- (Do this in your Windows IoT Core project)
4. Change the code from 3. like you want.

---

Notice: If you only want to send telemetry data to the cloud, without sending messages to the PI or without call methods on the PI from the Cloud, you should use the Event Hub. The Event Hub is much cheaper!!